# when click on button the time is count and show totall time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi gyzz i am new in jquery , when i click add button the running time is count suddenly when i click add button and its count , i click 3 times and its count different time and when i click totall button then show total time that i click 3 times add 3 different time , how this is possible... i use simple stopwatch plugin..
my code is

```js
(function( $ ){
//my code
     $('#demo1').stopwatch().stopwatch('start');
     //count time indually 
  $(".add_time").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var time_record = $('.example').find('#timer').text();
         var time_record++;
        console.log(time_record);
    });
    
    //get totall time 
      $(".totall_time").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    
    
    });



//stopwatch plugin
    function incrementer(ct, increment) {
        return function() { ct+=increment; return ct; };
    }
    
    function pad2(number) {
         return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    }

    function defaultFormatMilliseconds(millis) {
        var x, seconds, minutes, hours;
        x = millis / 1000;
        seconds = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x /= 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x /= 60;
        // hours = Math.floor(x % 24);
        // x /= 24;
        // days = Math.floor(x);
        return [pad2(minutes), pad2(seconds)].join(':');
    }

    //NOTE: This is a the 'lazy func def' pattern described at http://michaux.ca/articles/lazy-function-definition-pattern
    function formatMilliseconds(millis, data) {
        // Use jintervals if available, else default formatter
        var formatter;
        if (typeof jintervals == 'function') {
            formatter = function(millis, data){return jintervals(millis/1000, data.format);};
        } else {
            formatter = defaultFormatMilliseconds;
        }
        formatMilliseconds = function(millis, data) {
            return formatter(millis, data);
        };
        return formatMilliseconds(millis, data);
    }

    var methods = {
        
        init: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                updateInterval: 1000,
                startTime: 0,
                format: '{HH}:{MM}:{SS}',
                formatter: formatMilliseconds
            };
            
            // if (options) { $.extend(settings, options); }
            
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                
                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if (!data) {
                    // Setup the stopwatch data
                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                    data = settings;
                    data.active = false;
                    data.target = $this;
                    data.elapsed = settings.startTime;
                    // create counter
                    data.incrementer = incrementer(data.startTime, data.updateInterval);
                    data.tick_function = function() {
                        var millis = data.incrementer();
                        data.elapsed = millis;
                        data.target.trigger('tick.stopwatch', [millis]);
                        data.target.stopwatch('render');
                    };
                    $this.data('stopwatch', data);
                }
                
            });
        },
        
        start: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                // Mark as active
                data.active = true;
                data.timerID = setInterval(data.tick_function, data.updateInterval);
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        },
        
        stop: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                clearInterval(data.timerID);
                data.active = false;
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        },
        
        destroy: function() {
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                $this.stopwatch('stop').unbind('.stopwatch').removeData('stopwatch');
            });
        },
        
        render: function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('stopwatch');
            $this.html(data.formatter(data.elapsed, data));
        },

        getTime: function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('stopwatch');
            return data.elapsed;
        },
        
        toggle: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                if (data.active) {
                    $this.stopwatch('stop');
                } else {
                    $this.stopwatch('start');
                }
            });
        },
        
        reset: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                data.incrementer = incrementer(data.startTime, data.updateInterval);
                data.elapsed = data.startTime;
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        }
    };
    
    
    // Define the function
    $.fn.stopwatch = function( method ) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.stopwatch' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <div class="label">Count up from now</div>
  <div id="demo1" class="demo">00:00</div>
</div>
<button class="add_time">add</button>
<button class="totall_time">totall time</button>
```

Comment: in your first function you got this: `var time_record++;`. I think that's the problem.

Comment: i remeve var but in console NaN value show ..when i remove time_record++; then show count time but when click again its not add its show another count but i want this add previous count

Comment: plz anyone tell me how this is possible

Comment: Sorry but your question is very unclear

Comment: i include stopwatch jquery plugin and i want to add time for example i click add button then time ' 00:30 ' is pick and then i click again then time ' 00:50 ' is pick now i want to add this tow time 00:30 + 00:50 but its add after click on totall button that is my question how to solve this.. the time is running when i click add button then one time is pick and when i click again after few second then other time is pick now add this time and show after click totoal button ...